# Help drawing the function $\frac{100}{1+20e^{-0.23t}}$

Tags: graphing-functions

Can somebody explain this one to me?

Draw the function
$$p(t)=\frac{100}{1+20e^{-0.23t}}$$
for $t\in[-20,40]$.

Comment: it looks like P is described as a function of time, t is defined wierdly as t is normally time but it can apparently be negative, but beyond that, what ar eyou struggling to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a differential equation problem. The problem asks to draw the function

$$p(t) = \frac{100}{1 + 20e^{-0.23t}}$$

for $t \in [-20,40]$. You can use [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to give you an hint for what you wanna find and use calculus tools. Find the first and second derivatives, find were it is zero, find how this function behaves in that range. Is it crescent? Is it decreasing?

Comment: Which derivative tells you if it is crescent?